# Access Violation Error with wxDev

Tags: c++

Hi I am new to C++ coding, and I was given a a task that requires me to add 2 simple numbers together through using parameters.
I have checked my code with all my friends and it is fine, yet I am receiving the same error (There is an access violation in your program. Do you want to break it?)
In the output box its stopping at ("[New Thread 3120.0x1724]\n")

I am using wxDev-C++ and my pc is a windows7 64bit

My code:

```
using namespace std;

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

  int a,b;


  a = atoi (argv[1]);
  b = atoi (argv[2]);

  cout << a+b<< endl;
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Get smarter friends?  :)

Comment: Re: "Hi I am new to C++ coding" - [***Get an introductory C++ book and read it.***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) It will cover basic things like this and much, much more. It's a lot less frustrating that way.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing two args in the cmd line? How are you invoking the program?

Comment: One thing you need to do is check the size of argv[] before assigning using it. argc is the number of index's that are available in argv[] in your case it should not be less than 3

Comment: Yes I am passing 2 args through

Answer (score 0):

The code is right.Maybe you don't use the comand line correctly.